# I'm getting several errors that making no sense in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a 2d undertale style game and as part of it I need to transfer a list from an enemy object to an object that persists between scenes. So far the scripts are just implementing this feature
The EnemyScript

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour
{


    public int spears;
    public int axes;
    public int wizard;
    public int[] EnemyList;
    GameObject dataHolder;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        dataHolder = GameObject.Find("DataHolder");
        EnemyList = {spears, axes, wizard};

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void CollisionEnter2D(Collider2D otherObject){
        dataHolder.GetComponent<DataHolderScript>().enemies = EnemyList;

    }


}
```

And my DataHolderScript

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DataHolderScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int[] enemies;
    //int[] changeChecker = enemies;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

For some reason I'm getting these errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqK3j.png)

My goal was to transfer the EnemyList list from EnemyScript to the enemies list in DataHolderScript

Comment: You should try the following. ```EnemyList = new int[]{spears, axes, wizard};```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be initial errors while you're not assigning EnemyList as new List on `Start()`, try `EnemyList = new int[] { spears, axes, wizard };`

Comment: Thanks. I just implemented this and its working great. But now I can see that the list doesn't seem to be transferring to the DataHolder. I'm assuming this is the case because the public variable display on enemies isn't changing in the DataHolder object. Can you think of any reason for this? I think it was working when I had dataHolder.GetComponent<DataHolderScript>().enemies = EnemyList; in the Start method